# Search and match a pdf file with first 6 characters and open it in windows default program

Tags: c#

I am new to C# and programming. I will try to ask the question as clear as i can,

I have these pdf files in a folder, what i wanna do is i wanna match the name of the pdf files with first 6 letters of a string and if its exists i wanna open it in the windows default program.
For an example i have these files in a folder, name on each pdf file is more than 6 letters

- 87163437KJH.pdf
- 479562087gd.pdf
- 6489754378.pdf
- 571283874hgj.pdf
- 17236897467hdgr.pdf
- gefreg6834.pdf

I have this string "871634e3khsskdjfh" and i wanna take the first 6 letters "871634" and search for a pdf file that matches first 6 letters. If it is exist i wanna open it in windows default application. In this case "871634" is matching with 87163437KJH.pdf file and it should open

Another example;
I have this string "gefreg6df2352345" so the first 6 letters of the string is  "gefreg" It is matching with gefreg6834.pdf file so it should open that pdf.

I tried to use this method but I am stuck with putting thins together, please help

```
string[] files = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(@"J:\", txt_partnum.Text.Substring(0,6) +"*"+".pdf", System.IO.SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly);
            if (files.Length > 0)
            {
                Process.Start(@"J:\" + txt_partnum.Text.Substring(0,6)+"*"+".pdf");

            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Drawing doesnot exist in SE Drive !");
            }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you are almost there. Just need to iterate over the files:

```
string[] files = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(@"J:\", txt_partnum.Text.Substring(0,6) +"*"+".pdf", System.IO.SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly);
foreach (string file in files)
{
   Proccess.Start(file);
}
```

Comment: Dependind on how you interpret the need of the OP, you could only want to open the First one `if(files.Any()){Process.Start(files.First());}`